# How to fix InvalidAuthenticityToken in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm developing some API for my mobile application, and I got the following error in some POST action:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
```

Code of my ActionController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

I know how I can fix it through disabling CSRF verification, but in this case my API will be unsafe for CSRF attacks. Please, tell me, how to fix this error without disabling CSRF protection? Thanks. I use Rails 4.

Answer (score 1):

Rails only looks for an authenticity token for html/js requests, not json/xml ones, so this probably isn't an issue with rails, it's actually probably something to do with incorrect headers being passed in. Make sure you're passing in

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

client side, otherwise rails will think this is html. You can test this with curl:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://example.com/...
```

Also as a side note, as rails says, you should use

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

not

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

Comment: I.e. If I send the request from the mobile I needn't add any authenticity token

Comment: Your updates can't help me, because I don't want to disable verification. Why have you edited the first answer?

Comment: I've rolled back, my second way is nicer I suppose but I get where you are coming from. I still think it's kind of similar. I'm not 100% you can really protect yourself that well. You'd need HTTPS and an extra api call to do it. I suppose my question is, is it worth all that (extra server load and cost) just to ensure they're using your site and not something like curl?

Comment: They can't do anything themselves because I use some features for it. I want to protect my application for CSRF only. Please, tell me, if I send my params with content type 'application/json' I should encode them using JSON?

Comment: Is it possble to send request with Content-Type 'application/json' using Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

get the session[:_csrf_token] (you can create an api to get the csrf_token for the current session) before sending the post request so that you can send it with the parameters..Rails check for authenticity token for all requests other than GET.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L242